# How to know if there is a monotonic clock available?

Tags: java, clock, java-time

http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6458294

> The JVM will use CLOCK_MONOTONIC when available, and that should be
>   universally the case these days. It is up to the underlying platform
>   how to correctly implement CLOCK_MONOTONIC, but most of the issues
>   with unsychronized, frequency-unstable TSC usage should be behind us.
>   There are still potential issues in virtualized environments because
>   you can configure them such that the source underpinning
>   CLOCK_MONOTONIC is not monotonic - caveat emptor!

1) Is there a way to know if a monotonic clock is available in Java?

2) Is it up to the OS or the hardware?

3) How can I know which versions of Linux / Windows provide a monotonic clock?

Comment: The quote talks about virtual environments configured "badly". Otherwise it shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: The quote suggests that old systems may not have such a clock available.